# How to set an optional argument for function in python when taking value by sys.argv

Tags: python, argv, optional-arguments

I am writing a program to take 3 arguments from users.
The former two arguments are integer, and the third argument is a string and optional.

I know that None is used as a null default for optional arguments,
so I tried the following:

```
def main(w, l, s=None):
    variable_1 = w
    variable_2 = l
    variable_3 = s
...
...

main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), sys.argv[3])
```

However, if I put the third value isn't put, then the following error happens.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I believe it happens because the check for optional argument comes later than the timing that the system found the length of sys.argv array is not long enough.
So, how should I set the optional argument by using None as a default in a correct way in this case?
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Its not an issue with the function you created. Its the issue with your calling part where the `sys.argv` doesn't have 3rd index in it. So the exception was raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `IndexError: list index out of range` because it tries to take the third argument from `sys.argv`. But if you don't provide the third argument, It tries to pass the third argument to the function, which doesn't exists. To fix this you could do something like this-

```py
def main(w, l, s = None):
    variable_1 = w
    variable_2 = l
    variable_3 = s
...
...

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), sys.argv[3])
else:
    main(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), None)
```

This will only take the argument if it exists, else it will assign `None` to `variable_3`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume the possibility there is no third argument given. I would do it maybe like follows:

```
def main(argument):
    variable_1 = int(argument[0])
    variable_2 = int(argument[1])
    variable_3 = argument[2] if len(argument)>1 else None
...
...

main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood the subject and it works well now!